# How to convert socket.io in classic socket?

Tags: c, sockets, server, socket.io

I have a Java client and I need a C server. I use a socket.io framework in Java et I know how to create a C server, but I don't know how to listen to a specific room.
For example if I want to emit something like this in Java:

```
socket = IO.socket("http://myServer.fr:1234");
socket.emit("myRoom", "my message");
```

I don't know how to get the room in C.

Does anyone know?
Thanks!

Comment: what is room..?

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal C server to see how things are set up in your code. Also show the Java code defining the socket "myRoom".

Comment: Actually I don't know how to start in C. Do you see how does work socket.io in JavaScript, Java or Android? The emit function has two parameters : the room (or event) and the data.